# Updating ImageVIew in widget Android

Tags: android, widget, imageview, onupdate

When I want to update my ImegeView, i see "Problem loading widget";

My main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="280dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:background="@drawable/widget_bg"
>
<ImageView
android:name="@+id/image_in_widget"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

My Widget.java

```
package endoftheworld.wid;
//some imports

public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[]   appWidgetIds)
{
 RemoteViews updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.main); 
 Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.pulse);
 updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.image_in_widget,bitmap);
 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetIds, updateViews);
 super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds); 
  }
}
```

In DDMS I can see

```
AppWidgetHostView(128): android.widget.RemoteViews$ActionException: can't find view: 0x7f060000
```

But I have 0x7f060000 in R.java

```
 //....
public static final class id {
    public static final int image_in_widget=0x7f060000;
}
 //...
```

I using Android Platform 2.3.1 API Level 9 CPU/ABI ARM (armeabi).

What's a trick?

Answer (score 0):

The `R.layout.main` layout you're passing to `RemoteViews` doesn't have any view with the ID `R.id.image_in_widget`. Perhaps you meant to pass a different layout, or perhaps the `ImageView` in that layout has the wrong ID.